# Add Constraint with animation to view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

hey I'm trying to bring inside a view with changing it's constraint with this code

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 500, animations: {
        self.forgetTopConstraint.isActive = false
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.forgetPasswordView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    })
```

`forgetTopConstraint` is a constraint that anchors `forgetPasswordView`'s top to `view`'s bottom with constant 0 so the `forgetTopConstraint` is out of view then I'm trying to animate it inside to the center of `view` with that code but it's appearing suddenly not with animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your surrounding code or view setup, it sounds like you just need to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the containing view. That's the method that actually performs the work of applying updated constraints. `layoutIfNeeded` is triggered automatically by a number of other changes to the view, but in the case of wanting it to animate, you actually don't need to call any of your other layout changes inside the animation block. Just call the one statement and that should cause it to animate all your previous changes:

```
self.forgetTopConstraint.isActive = false
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.forgetPasswordView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
UIView.animate(withDuration: 500, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    
})
```

Comment: I was 5 seconds away from the exact same answer, down to the "without seeing more code". Good answer.